# using sqlite as database for angular v7

Tags: sqlite, angular7

I am building a small SPA with angular and since I am new to angular,  I am using the angular tutorial as a road map for my application. all things are working find until the retrieving data from sqlite database (due to implementation restriction, use of any other type of backend code is not possible). the tutorial (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) uses a in-memory-database which is obviously is not fitted for me. I want to have service that retrieves data from sqlite and could be injected to component

**component**

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { Areport } from '../../classess/areport';
   import { ReportService } from "../../services/report.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-daily-report',
  templateUrl: './daily-report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./daily-report.component.css']
})
export class DailyReportComponent implements OnInit {
  reports : Areport[];
  constructor(private reportService: ReportService) { }
  getReports(): void {
    this.reportService.getReports()
        .subscribe( reports => this.reports = reports)
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getReports();
  }
}
```

**reportService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { Areport } from "../classess/areport";
import { MessageService } from "./message.service";
import { SqlitedbService } from "./sqlitedb.service";

@Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' })


export class ReportService {

  constructor( private messageService: MessageService) { } 
  getReports(): Observable<Areport[]>{
    this.messageService.add('reportService: fetched reports');
    return of(SqlitedbService.R()); 


}
```

**sqlite service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
const  sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('../../db/my.db');
let reports : any
db.all("SELECT * FROM reports",[],(err:any,rows:any)=>{
  reports=rows;
})

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SqlitedbService {

  constructor(){}
  R(){ return reports};
}
```

i couldn't find any type of tutorial for using sqlite in angular excet this (https://github.com/leota/electron-angular4-sqlite3/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts) which i have no idea what is it doing and or neither worth trying to add more layers such as electron

the ideal for me would be some type of class function that i can use in my service for returning some query result and performing insert statement

also this piece of js code works fine in node but i don't know how to use it in angular

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./my.db')
db.each("SELECT * FROM reports", function(err, row)  {
  console.log(err+"   "+row.id + ": " + row.txt);
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the following tutorial : https://appdividend.com/2019/06/04/angular-8-tutorial-with-example-learn-angular-8-crud-from-scratch/

In this tutorial, he use mongoDb, but I have replaced mongodb with sqlite3 this way :

1. sqlite must be in backend of your app. So create an api folder at the root of your project and do npm init -y
2. npm install express body-parser cors --save
3. install sqlite npm install sqlite3 --save
4. install nodemon : npm install nodemon --save-dev and npm install -g nodemon
5. create a server.js

```
const express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cors = require('cors'),
sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

db.serialize(function () {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
    }

    stmt.finalize();

    db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function (err, row) {
        console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
    });
});

db.close();

const app = express();
let port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const server = app.listen(function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

6. launch your server with nodemon ./server.js
   and the result is :

Listening on port 4000
1: Ipsum 0 
2: Ipsum 1 
3: Ipsum 2 
4: Ipsum 3 
5: Ipsum 4 
6: Ipsum 5 
7: Ipsum 6 
8: Ipsum 7 
9: Ipsum 8 
10: Ipsum 9

Comment: and how to get data from this server.js? how to execute request an get the response in angular?

anyway it is useless as app-usage when i need to run another thing from console

OP wants same as me, load DB in angular app in browser then manipulate in DB in angular-app

I also cant find any useful examples for it - is it possible?